# Solving $2^{2n-3}=32(n-1)$ for $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, exponentiation

Just wondering is there any way to solve this equation using some algebraic or calculus tricks but without graphs.

> Solve for $n$ 
>   $$2^{2n-3}=32(n-1)$$

I solved this intuitively or to be more specific we can solving sigh equations by substituting $n=1,2,3,...$ but what if the solution of $n$ not belongs to integer set.

Any ideas ? I just want a general algebraic approach.

Comment: Look up the lambert W function

Comment: If there's a solution that isn't an integer, then there's no algebraic trick to find it. The best you can do is numerical methods, such as Newton's Method, q.v.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Small correction: the similar equation $4^{2n-1}=32(n-1)$ has a non integer root ($n=\frac 32$) that's easy to find by inspection. I think you meant irrational rather than integral.

Comment: @Deepak, yes, careless of me. Though I was referring to the particular equation OP is asking about.

Answer (score 4):

The solutions are $$1 - \frac{W(-\ln(2)/32)}{2 \ln(2)} $$
where $W$ is a branch of the Lambert W function.  The real solutions are obtained with the principal branch (approximately $1.015974889$) and the "$-1$" branch ($5$).

EDIT: In general, if you suspect an equation involving exponentials may have a solution of the form $x = a + b W(c)$, the approach is to try to put it into the form 
$z e^z = c$ with a substitution $x = a + b z$.  In your case,
$2^{2x-3} = 32(x-1)$ can be written as
$$ (x-1) \exp((3-2x)\ln(2)) = 1/32$$
If $x = 1 - y$, that's
$$ - 64 y \exp(2 \ln(2) y) = 1 $$
so with $z = 2 \ln(2) y$ it's 
$$ z e^z = - \frac{\ln(2)}{32} $$
And then $z = W(-\ln(2)/32)$.  Since $-e^{-1} < -\ln(2)/32 < 0$, you get 
real solutions with either the principal or the $-1$ branch.

Comment: I don't want the answer... As I said I know the answer...I want the approach.

Comment: You didn‘t sound like you knew the general solution in your opening question? Did you even look up the Lambert W function? The approach is quite straightforward once you know what it is.

Comment: How do you know the answer, Aman, if you don't know an approach?

Comment: Why doesn't your answer shows that n=5 is also a solution ?

Comment: @AmanRajput:  It does: look at the line that says `... and the "-1" branch (5).`

Comment: The fact that $W_{-1}(-\ln(2)/32) = -8 \ln(2)$ is not exactly obvious, though.

Answer (score 3):

Consider that you look for the zero's of function
$$f(x)=2^{2x-3}-32(x-1)$$
By inspection, $f(0)=\frac{257}{8}$, $f(1)=\frac 12$, $f(2)=-30$; so, a solution close to $x=1$.

Perform a Taylor expansion around $x=1$ (this is equivalent to the first interation of Newton method); it will give
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}+(x-1) (\log (2)-32)+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, this would give, as an *estimate*,
$$x=\frac{2 \log (2)-65}{2 (\log (2)-32)}\approx 1.015970944$$

We could do better building a $[1,n]$ Padé approximant; in such a way, the estimate is obtained solving a linear equation in $(x-1)$. For example, the simplest (corresponding to the first iteration of Halley method) would be
$$f(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{ \left(2048+\log ^2(2)-128 \log (2)\right)}{2 (\log
   (2)-32)}(x-1)}{1-\frac{ \log ^2(2)}{\log (2)-32}(x-1)}$$ giving
$$x=\frac{2080+\log ^2(2)-129 \log (2)}{2048+\log ^2(2)-128 \log (2)}\approx 1.015974860$$ We could continue the process and get the following results

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n &  x_{(n)} \\
 0 &  1.0159709442173479658 \\
 1 &  1.0159748596445568773 \\
 2 &  1.0159748895153359604 \\
 3 &  1.0159748896898660072 \\
 4 &  1.0159748896907116852 \\
 5 &  1.0159748896907153030 \\
 6 &  1.0159748896907153175
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If we are concerned by the roots, consider that
$$f'(x)=2^{2 x-2} \log (2)-32 \qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=2^{2 x-1} \log ^2(2) \,\, > 0 \,\,\forall x$$ The first derivative cancels at
$$x_*=1+\frac{\log \left(\frac{32}{\log (2)}\right)}{2 \log (2)}\implies f(x_*)=\frac{16 \left(1+\log \left(\frac{\log (2)}{32}\right)\right)}{\log (2)} <0$$ So, two roots. To *approximate* them, build a Taylor series around $x_*$ to get 
$$f(x)=f(x_*)+\frac 12 f''(x_*) (x-x_*)^2+O((x-x_*)^2)$$ and solve the quadratic; this will give $x_1=2.05$ and $x_2=5.48$. Using thse guesses, Newton method should converge quite fast.

Comment: Why doesn't your solution shows that n=5 is also a valid solution ?

Comment: I guess that's because you said that you found the integer solution and you wanted to find the non-integral one.

Comment: @AmanRajput. Have a look at my edit.